# Find the size of photos and videos inside (Photo Library) iOS device using Photos Framework on iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, ios9, photos, photosframework, assetslibrary

Till iOS 7 we were using Assets Library Framework to get the total size of photos and videos in iOS device, look here : 
[How to find total size for images and videos inside photo library in iOS](https://kashiftriffort.wordpress.com/2013/07/09/how-to-find-total-size-for-images-and-video-inside-photo-library-in-ios/)

Can anyone please help me do the same using Photos Framework as Assets Library Framework is deprecated. Also how can I calculate the total size if there are large number of photos in a faster manner.
You can see in this app :
[MobiShield for iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/app/mobishield/id453189033?mt=8) here if you go to More > Disk you can see that the developer is calculating the total photos size and videos size in 2 seconds. How can I achieve this ? In Objective - C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use these :

```
- (NSUInteger)updateVideoCount
{
    ALAuthorizationStatus status = [ALAssetsLibrary authorizationStatus];
    if (status==ALAuthorizationStatusDenied) {
        [self goToSettingsAlert];
    }
videoCount = 0;
totalVideoSize = 0;

ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

[assetLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
    [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allVideos]];
    [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        if (asset)
        {
            NSString *type = [asset  valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType];
            if ([type isEqualToString:ALAssetTypeVideo])
            {
                videoCount++;

                ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                totalVideoSize += rep.size;
            }

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }];
    if(group==nil)
    {
        [self loadTable];
        descTable.hidden = NO;
        [descTable reloadData];
    }
} failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {
}];

return 0;
```

}

```
- (NSUInteger)updatePictureCount
{
    photoCount = 0;
    totalPictureSize = 0;

    ALAssetsLibrary *assetLibrary = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    [assetLibrary enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupAll usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];
        [group enumerateAssetsUsingBlock:^(ALAsset *asset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
            if (asset)
            {
                NSString *type = [asset  valueForProperty:ALAssetPropertyType];
                if ([type isEqualToString:ALAssetTypePhoto])
                {
                    photoCount++;

                    ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [asset defaultRepresentation];
                    totalPictureSize += rep.size;
                }

            }

            else
            {

            }
        }];
        if(group==nil)
        {

            [self loadTable];
            descTable.hidden = NO;
            [descTable reloadData];
        }
    } failureBlock:^(NSError *error) {

    }];

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

User Photo Assets (I have not used yet but this is IOS 8 requirement) or ALASSETS that is deprecated but still working with current versions , this will give you the file information.